# Replace a string in a multidimensional Array

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, replace

Below is my code that I have. I need to replace any words of the matrix that is 8 characters long to be "***". What is the most simplest way to replace the words in the array.

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] original = {
                { "Oluchi", "Mohammed", "Kylo", "Daniel" },
                { "Barry", "Jonathan", "Cylee", "Themshni" },
                { "Jason", "Ramazani", "Anrich", "Ashley" },
                { "Sianne", "Blessing", "Callum", "Tyrone" } };
        System.out.println("Printing Matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(original[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] matrix = {
                { "Oluchi", "Mohammed", "Kylo", "Daniel" },
                { "Barry", "Jonathan", "Cylee", "Themshni" },
                { "Jason", "Ramazani", "Anrich", "Ashley" },
                { "Sianne", "Blessing", "Callum", "Tyrone" } };

        print(matrix);
        System.out.println();
        mask(matrix, 8, "***");
        print(matrix);
    }

    private static void print(String[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                if (col > 0)
                    System.out.print(' ');
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void mask(String[][] matrix, int length, String str) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
                if (matrix[row][col].length() == length)
                    matrix[row][col] = str;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Oluchi Mohammed Kylo Daniel
Barry Jonathan Cylee Themshni
Jason Ramazani Anrich Ashley
Sianne Blessing Callum Tyrone

Oluchi *** Kylo Daniel
Barry *** Cylee ***
Jason *** Anrich Ashley
Sianne *** Callum Tyrone
```

Comment: The OP will learn a lot when people just drop solutions on him. Or not.

Comment: @GhostCat The OP can compare two solutions and find out the way hot it could be solved. I hope that next exersize will be more clear to the OP.